# WebSoket in Charles

Tags: websocket, spring-websocket, charles-proxy

I try to investigate WebSockets using Charles.
But on WebSocket tab I see only that message:
[image]

But I didn't set up any limits for WebSockets. 
[image]

With what it can be connected? Maybe I should check another settings?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found a decision, that solved my problem. But I still see the same message on WebSockets tab. Here is my way:

1. Click right button on WebSocket
2. Choose "Save WebSocket messages..."
3. And it exports all the messages to separate .txt files. The other useful thing, that in the name of the file you can find the mark, which helps to understand by whom the message was sent: by the client or by the server.

[image]